# How to force shutdown windows 10 via openSSH connection

Tags: windows, shutdown, openssh

I have installed OpenSSH on my windows 10 PC, and I can also connect from remote NAS server via an ssh connection to this windows after I got ssh connection, I was trying to perform `shutdown /s /f /t 0` but got the `Access is denied. (5)` error, but if performing `shutdown /h` did work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I was using Administrator to connect to windows PC via openSSH, but the service itself is running as local system account, maybe this is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the reason. The user Administrator has no force remote shutdown permission. After adding user Administrator to Policy 'Force shutdown from a remote system' in 'User Rights Assignment' in 'Security Settings', this command works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
shutdown -s -t 00 -f
```

this will force shutdown windows OS where -s is shutdown , -t indicates time and -f makes force shutdown

Comment: please try `shutdown /s /m \\chris-laptop /t 30 /c “Shutting down for maintenance.” /d P:1:1` where \\chris-laptop is target system